# Programmatically querying via SearchApiAcquiaSearchService

Tags: search, acquia-cloud

I am working on a site where querying using **SearchApiSolrService** is successful. However, when I deploy to Acquia Cloud and attempt to access the Acquia Search using the **SearchApiAcquiaSearchService** I get a 403 Forbidden.

Response

```
SearchApiException: "403" Status: Forbidden: Forbidden in SearchApiSolrConnection->checkResponse() (line 544 of ...sites/all/modules/contrib/search_api_solr/includes/solr_connection.inc).
```

The subscription information is correct (via Acquia Agent). Here's a piece of the code:

Code Sample

```
$server = search_api_server_load('my_acquia_solr_server');
$index = search_api_index_load('my_base_index');
$query = new SearchApiQuery($index);
$query = ... lots of random filters here that work for SearchApiSolrService calls so ignoring ...
$solr = new SearchApiAcquiaSearchService($server);
$result = $solr->search($query);
```

Thoughts?

Note: If you were to replace the **SearchApiAcquiaSearchService** with the regular **SearchApiSolrService**, the non-Acquia versions of the site integrate with Solr perfectly fine.

Comment: i've also asked this question on d.o here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2771891

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this (also updated on the Drupal.org node commented above) is:

To skip this part:

```
$solr = new SearchApiAcquiaSearchService($server);
$result = $solr->search($query);
```

And simply do:

```
$result = $query->execute();
```